# Choose Variable With Highest Value (Python)

Tags: python

How do I make Python choose the variable with the hightest integer value?

E.g

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = 3
d = 0
```

I want the output to be "
c". I know the max() command does something similar, but instead of choosing the *variable itself*, it will choose the hightest *number*.
If I wasn't clear enough about this please tell me and I'll try and reexplain, but it seems to be a simple enough matter of not knowing the command. Thanks in advance!

Comment: is "c" the variable with the highest integer value in your example ???  .. What about "d" which is equal to 4 ?

Comment: sorry, I forgot to make "d" equal to 0. my bad.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a job for a dictionary:

```
data = {
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2,
    'c': 3,
    'd': 4
}
print max(data, key=data.get)
```

```
d
```

Python does not make a point of tracking variable names.

Comment: I'd argue the case that it's *a job for a dictionary* - even then I'd avoid the `lambda` and use `max(data, key=data.__getitem__)` (or `.get`) (they save an extra function call overhead)

Comment: Not understanding your emphasis there. `.get` sounds good here, since the `None` behavior can never occur.

Comment: Consider the variables given in a list ``variables = [a, b, c, d]`` as starting point. How would you get to your dictionary from there (automatically)?

Comment: @Eric and since the error can never occur, calling `__getitem__` directly makes that explicit and avoids the internals of `get` (think of it either doing a contains check or try/except KeyError block) trying to do so... (although, yeah, `data.get` does just *look* nicer)

Comment: To create the dictionary ``data`` you can do ``variables = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`` followed by ``data = {name: val for name, val in locals().iteritems() if name in variables}``. Then this would be really answering the question.

Comment: @Nras: The real answer to the problem is _"You don't want to get there from here"_

Comment: @JonClements: Indeed. Not a fan of using `__dunders__` directly, so went for the looks nice option