# How to find greatest integer in array with Python?

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to find the greatest integer in a list with Python but the thing is I don't want the greatest value, I would like to find the integer with the greatest value on array. Is there any way to
do this?

The array I am trying to find the integer with greatest value was like that;

```
int1, int2, int3, int4, int5 = 5, 10, 20, 15, 5

line = [ int1, int2, int3, int4, int5]
```

And I would like get the integer with a greatest value (in that case int3) but instead they are not fixed in the code I wrote.

Comment: You are treating variable names like they are values. This doesn't really work. If you want values like "int3" you should use a dictionary or a list. Any time you are using variables like `int1`, `int2`... you should probably be using a list and then referencing `my_list[1]` `my_list[2]`, etc.

Comment: [Related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25743426/choose-variable-with-highest-value-python) which suggests using a dictionary of variable names and values since Python does not track variable names.

Comment: Yeah, you guys are totally true. I was looking for the index of an integer actually, I am sorry for explaining it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are looking for the index value of the largest number in the list you can use the following.

```
>>> ls = [5,10,20,15,5]
>>> ls.index(max(ls))
2
>>> ls[2]
20
```

Comment: Thanks so much, not the exact code but ls.index() method totally works.